# Best way to find element in csv python

Tags: python, csv

I have a very big csv file with more than 50K entries and increasing. My file has this structure:

```
    ID;name;battery;... 
    101;a,3.3;...
    102;b,3.3;...
    103;c,3.2;...
```

I know how to read a csv file in python but I want to know what could be the best way to find if a new entry is on the csv file to avoid rewrite a new line.

I was doing something like this:

```
if new_id in open(log.csv).read():
```

Any help or advice would be highly appreciated.

EDIT: I want to filter by ID

Comment: Do you want to check if the whole line `103;c,3.2,...` is in the file, or just the `id`?

Comment: What do you mean by `to avoid rewrite a new line` ?

Comment: I am smelling a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to find if an 'ID' was written to decide writing a new line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good way to avoid repetitions is to use special data structure, optimized for search. In Python you may use `set()`, for example. `set()` is based on hash-tables and provides search with time complexity `O(n)`. The schema is as follows:

Read the existing ids from file into `set()`:

```
file = open('log.csv', 'rw')
# include only ids to set:
entries = set(i.split(',')[0] for i in file.readlines()[1:])
```

Check condition every new row insert:

```
# new_entry - is a new line
new_id = new_entry.split(',')[0] # get new id
if new_id not in entries:
    file.write(new_entry)  # Maybe newline appending is needed
    entries.add(new_id) # Update a set of existing rows
```